# How to show library selection option in UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using simple default UIImagePickerController but I want the photo library option to be shown in UIImagePickerController as like normal camera in iphone/ipod. 
I want to user default imagepicker with out any overlayView.
How can I enable it?

Thank you.

Comment: You want the user to select from the photo library without having to present the option?

Answer (score 0):

To implement this functionality you will have to use a camera overlay. There are a lot of resources to learn about camera overlay one being http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html

If you really want the default apple `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` 'look'

1.Set the your `uiimagepicker`'s `showCameraControls` property to `YES`.

2.In your customoverlay file(.xib) have nothing but the album `button` and do what you intend to.

Hope this helps :)